# Reorder RegEx Capture Groups in same expression

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have log files with this timestamp format: [04/Apr/2021:12:21:24 +0000]

This RegEx matches this format:

```
\[([0-9]{2})\/([A-Za-z]{3})\/([0-9]{4}):([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) ([+-][0-9]{4})\]
```

Is it possible to add the following modifying this expression?

1. Reorder date to YYYY-MM-DD by reordering the captured groups
2. Change Month Abbreviation to equivalent month number (Apr to 04)

These changes are needed to import Fastly logs into an AWS Athena Database using the date/time from the logs as input to a SQL timestamp column key.

I've searched all over Google and Stack Overflow, but only find substitution as a separate expression.

Any help is greatly appreciated; thanks!

UPDATE:
Here is my Athena Create Table statement where my Regular Expression is used to populate the data from my Fastly Logs.

```
create external table if not exists logsdb.service_logs_2021_04_04
(
   `syslog_prefix`            string,
   `remote_ip_address`        string,
   `dashes`                   string,
   `timestamp`                timestamp,
   `url_request`              string,
   `final_status_code`        smallint,
   `response_size`            int,
   `fastly_datacenter`        string,
   `fastly_cache_state`       string,
   `client_ip_address`        string,
   `client_geo_location`      string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
(
   'serialization.format' = '1',
   'input.regex' = '^(.+]:) ([0-9.]+) ("-" "-") \\[([0-9]{2})\/([A-Za-z]{3})\/([0-9]{4}):([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}) ([+-][0-9]{4})\\] \"(.+?)\" ([0-9]{3}) ([0-9]+) ([A-Za-z]+) ([A-Za-z-]+) ([0-9.]+) ([A-Za-z ]+)$'
)
LOCATION 's3://weblog-query-source/service-logs/2021-04-04/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

Comment: You will have to do that in client code.  It is not practical to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` that is available in MySQL 8.0.

Comment: Unlike most programming languages, MySQL `REGEXP_REPLACE()` can't copy capture groups into the replacement, so you can't use it to rearrange the string. It also can't call functions, so there's no other way to transform data. It's very limited.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way around the complicated regex is to convert the values using `SELECT` query. For example:

```
select date_format(date_parse('04/Apr/2021:12:21:24', '%d/%b/%Y:%T%'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Will output: `2021-04-04`